# Why doesn't restore_best_weights=True update results?

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, early-stopping

I found that `restore_best_weights=True` does not actually restore the best behavior. A simplified example with some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import set_random_seed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

np.random.seed(1)
set_random_seed(2)

x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
y = np.array([1., 3., 4., 2., 5.])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(1, ), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(4,                    activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.1), loss='mse')
stopmon = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2, restore_best_weights=True, verbose=1)
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=2, callbacks=[stopmon])
res = model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=1)
print(f'best={stopmon.best:.4f}, loss={res:.4f}')
```

The output (on my system) is:

```
Epoch 1/100
1/1 - 0s - loss: 11.8290 - 434ms/epoch - 434ms/step
Epoch 2/100
1/1 - 0s - loss: 1.9091 - 0s/epoch - 0s/step
Epoch 3/100
1/1 - 0s - loss: 1.5159 - 16ms/epoch - 16ms/step
Epoch 4/100
1/1 - 0s - loss: 1.3921 - 0s/epoch - 0s/step
Epoch 5/100
1/1 - 0s - loss: 1.6787 - 0s/epoch - 0s/step
Epoch 6/100
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch: 4.
1/1 - 0s - loss: 2.0629 - 33ms/epoch - 33ms/step
Epoch 6: early stopping
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 100ms/step - loss: 1.6787
best=1.3921, loss=1.6787
```

It looks like the weights *are* set to those from epoch 4. Then why does the loss still evaluate to the higher value from epoch 6? Is there anything extra I should do to update the model or something?

I use an up-to-date TensorFlow (version 2.12.0) on Windows x64 (Intel), `tf.version.COMPILER_VERSION == 'MSVC 192930140'`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your training. For one, I am confused that your loss increases altough you always present the same input. When I reproduced the code, my loss was always decreasing. But I also used another tensorflow version ('2.3.1') and only a CPU. Due to my tf version, I could not use set_random_seed but instead I used random.seed(seed), np.random.seed(seed), tf.random.set_seed(seed), which is equivalent according to the tf docs.

Comment: It increases because it overshoots (`learning_rate=0.1`).

Comment: Early-stopping only makes sense if you have a validation dataset. The goal of early-stopping is to find when continuing training would lead to overfitting of the model, at which point it return the best model _in terms of the validation loss_. Put another way, the validation loss is used as a proxy for how well the model will generalize to (i.e., perform on) the test data. I suspect that the `EarlyStopping` may have undefined behavior when no validation data is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the loss calculation for the training loss.
**But it still works, at least for the val_loss.**
I have done 2 tests

1_Without validation:

```
np.random.seed(1)
set_random_seed(2)

x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(1,), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.1), loss='mse')
stopmon = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2, restore_best_weights=True,    verbose=1)
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=2, callbacks=[stopmon])
res = model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=1)
print(f'best={stopmon.best:.4f}, loss={res:.4f}')
```

The output is:

```
Epoch 1/100
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9681 - 468ms/epoch - 15ms/step
Epoch 2/100
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9515 - 33ms/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 3/100
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9675 - 30ms/epoch - 953us/step
Epoch 4/100
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch: 2.
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9596 - 37ms/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 4: early stopping
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 952us/step - loss: 1.0256
best=0.9515, loss=1.0256
```

You can see, its very strange that the loss is higher than the rest. Maybe due how the calculate the loss in the training step.

2_With validation step.

```
np.random.seed(1)
set_random_seed(2)

x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)

x2 = np.random.randn(50)
y2 = np.random.randn(50)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(1,), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.1), loss='mse')
stopmon = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, restore_best_weights=True, verbose=1)
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=2, callbacks=[stopmon], validation_data=(x2, y2))
res = model.evaluate(x2, y2, verbose=1)
print(f'best={stopmon.best:.4f}, loss={res:.4f}')
```

And the output is:

```
Epoch 1/100
32/32 - 1s - loss: 0.9681 - val_loss: 1.0496 - 626ms/epoch - 20ms/step
Epoch 2/100
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.9901 - 57ms/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 3/100
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9675 - val_loss: 1.0150 - 57ms/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 4/100
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch: 2.
32/32 - 0s - loss: 0.9596 - val_loss: 1.0154 - 57ms/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 4: early stopping
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9901
best=0.9901, loss=0.9901
```

**You can see that in this case they match. So in conclusion, we can say it works with val_loss and it has a strange loss calculation in the training step.**

Comment: This makes sense, as `loss` is before updating the weights and `val_loss` is after.